# Using Python Flask to change the colour of an icon when it detects a words like scam, pending and verified

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to change the colour of a circle icon next to words like scam, pending and verified. Which is already displayed on the page So that when the page loads the corresponding colour for the icon  would be displayed. I have attached my code

```js
import os
from app import app,db
from datetime import timedelta
from flask import render_template, request, flash,url_for,redirect,session,make_response,send_from_directory, send_file
from app.models import User,Watch,Group,Contact,Advert,Report,Tv
from app.stock_function import is_valid_email, check_login
import hashlib
import smtplib
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from config import Config

from flask_mail import Mail, Message
mail = Mail(app)



@app.route('/whatsapptv')
def whatsapptv():
    tv= Tv.query.all()
    return render_template('tvlist.html',tvs=tv)
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div  class="center-div" style="width: auto">

          </div>
          {%if tvs %}

<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
                <div class="row">
                    <thead>
                        <th scope="col">S/N</th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
                        <th scope="col"> Verified Business</th>
                        <th scope="col"> Remark</th>



                      </thead>
                {%for tv in tvs%}

                        <tr>
                       <td> <h5>{{loop.index}}</h5></td>
                       <td> <h5>{{tv.name}}</h5></td>
                     <td><h4 >{{tv.group}}</h4>                  </td>
                  <td><h4>{{tv.description}} </h4> <i class="bx bxs-circle"></i> </td>
                    <td><h4 >{{tv.remark}}</h4>                  </td>

                  </td>
                      </tr>


                {%endfor%}
                </table>
                </div>
          {%else%}
                <p>No Business available</p>
          {%endif%}
      </div>

<div>
```

Comment: Create a style for each word in your page. Check for those words and add the corresponding style before sending then to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change "parameter" by the parameter you're using in your model to define the color.

```
                    <tr>
                   <td> <h5>{{loop.index}}</h5></td>
                   <td> <h5>{{tv.name}}</h5></td>
                 <td><h4 >{{tv.group}}</h4></td>
              <td><h4>{{tv.description}} </h4> 
                {% if tv.parameter == 'verified' %}<i class="bx" style="color:green;" bxs-circle"></i>
                {% elif tv.parameter == 'pending' %}<i class="bx" style="color:yellow;" bxs-circle"></i>
                {% else %}<i class="bx" style="color:red;" bxs-circle"></i>{% endif %}</td>
                <td><h4 >{{tv.remark}}</h4></td>

              </td>
                  </tr>
```